# Python public holidays that fall on a weekday

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, date, datetime

I've managed to find two (fairly comprehensive) holiday packages which are:

- [Python | Holidays library](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-holidays-library/)
- [workalendar (7.1.0)](https://pypi.org/project/workalendar/)

**End Goal:**

I would like to get a `int` by using either of these two packages for the public holidays that *only* fall on a week day. The country is Australia and the state is Western Australia (WA), where both packages can accommodate for states and territories of Australia.

**MWE:**

```
import numpy as np
start_date = "2019-01-01"
end_date = "2020-01-01"

total_working_days = np.busday_count(start_date, end_date)
# total_public_holidays_that_fall_on_working_days = 
#             use the holidays package to get the number of public holidays
#             that fall on working days (Mon-Fri) between *start_date* and
#             *end_date*.

actual_working_days = total_working_days - total_public_holidays_that_fall_on_working_days
```

**Question:**

I want to get an `int` for the actual number of working days (working days - public holidays that fall on weekdays), how can I do this with either of the above libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [workalendar](https://peopledoc.github.io/workalendar/basic.html), adapted to your requirements:

```
from datetime import datetime
from workalendar.oceania.australia import WesternAustralia

start_date = "2019-01-01"
end_date = "2020-01-01"

start_datetime = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
end_datetime = datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d')

cal = WesternAustralia()

print(cal.get_working_days_delta(start_datetime, end_datetime))
```

**Output:**

```
252
```